# How to map a list of objects for editing and saving

Tags: java, groovy, controller, mapping, playframework

I am trying to edit a list of entities and update or create them afterwards.
In my controller I have:

```
public static void editTargets(@Required @Min(2011) Integer year, @Required String type, @Required Long groupId) {
    RetailRegion region = RetailRegion.findById(groupId);
    notFoundIfNull(region);
    TargetType tType = TargetType.valueOf(type);
    notFoundIfNull(tType);

    List<Target> targets = Target.findByGroupAndTypeAndYear(region, tType, year);

    if (targets != null && !targets.isEmpty()) {
        render(targets, year, tType, region);
    }
    createTargets(year, type, groupId);
}

public static void createTargets(@Required @Min(2011) Integer year, @Required String type, @Required Long groupId) {
    RetailRegion region = RetailRegion.findById(groupId);
    notFoundIfNull(region);
    TargetType tType = TargetType.valueOf(type);
    notFoundIfNull(tType);

    render(region, year, tType);
}

public static void saveTargets(@Required List<Target> targets) {
    notFoundIfNull(targets);

    for (Target target : targets) {
        if (target != null)
            target.save();
    }

    flash.success("Targets have been saved.");
    if (params.get("_save") != null) {
        mgmt();
    }
    mgmt();
}
```

and my editTargets template:

```
  #{form id:'targetsForm', method:'POST', action:@saveTargets()}
  <section id="targets">
    <table  width="750px" id="targetsTable">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>January</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        %{int i = 0;}%
        #{list items:targets, as:'target'}
        <tr>
          #{field 'target.id'}
            <input id="${field.id}" type="hidden" name="${field.name}" value="${field.value}" class="${field.errorClass}" />
          #{/field}
          <td class="center">${targets[i].code}</td>
          <td class="center">
          #{field 'target.jan'}
            <input id="${field.id}" type="number" name="${field.name}" value="${field.value}" class="${field.errorClass}" />
          #{/field}
          </td>
          ...
```

The problem I have is that I do not seem to be able to map back the edited targets in the **saveTargets** controller method.

The controller will map the fields back to a String array for each field  (i.e. target.jan --> String[]) instead of a List`<Targets`>.

Is there a way to map my object back to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looping through targets in your view so your field tags should include the fact that they're in a list/array.  It's interesting that target.jan is somehow coming though as a String array though.  I think your field tag should look something like this:

```
%{ fieldName = "target[${i}].jan" }%
#{field "${fieldName}"}
    ...
#{/field}
```

The above is for the 'jan' property, so you'll have to do the same for any other target properties you have in the view (e.g. id)

Comment: I am now doing something similar which 'nearly works' with         #{list items:targets, as:'target'}
        <tr>
          <input type="hidden" name="targets[${i}]_id}" value="${target.id}"/>
          <td class="center">
            <input type="number" name="targets[${i}]_jan" value="${target.jan}"/>
          </td>

Comment: I say nearly works as the fields get mapped correctly in the targets list. For some reason only the id does not get mapped, which is kind of annoying as this is the key to updating the model. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try it using the code I provided in my answer? if so, what happened then?